# NonlinearModelFit returning nonsense for very simple data

Tags: fitting, data

In fitting the following data, if I first log transform the y-values and use `LinearModelFit` I get a set of parameters that fits the data:

```
data = {{248, 0.032}, {280, 0.0498}, {327, 0.0971}, {360, 0.162}};
loggedData = ReplaceList[data, {__, {x_Integer, y_Real}, ___} -> {x, Log[y]}];
linFit = LinearModelFit[loggedData, t, t];

linFit["BestFitParameters"]

{-7.03516, 0.0144417}
```

However, if I instead use `NonlinearModelFit` on the data directly (not log transformed), I get nonsense

```
data = {{248, 0.032}, {280, 0.0498}, {327, 0.0971}, {360, 0.162}};
NonlinearModelFit[data, a Exp[b t], {a, b}, t]["BestFitParameters"] 

{a -> 0., b -> 1.}
```

Have I found the one set of points that `NonlinearModelFit` cannot handle? It seems that any other exponential data I feed in can be fit just fine by `NonlinearModelFit`. Are there any additional directives I can give to `NonlinearModelFit` to get a sensible result?

Comment: This is another case of having to give reasonable starting values when you have a function that depends exponentially on the parameters (cf. [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20285/)). Try `NonlinearModelFit[data, a Exp[b t], {{a, 0}, {b, 0}}, t]["BestFitParameters"]` and you will find that it works correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `Method -> "NMinimize"` to the NonlinearModelFit call.

```
data = {{248, 0.032}, {280, 0.0498}, {327, 0.0971}, {360, 0.162}};
NonlinearModelFit[data, a Exp[b t], {a, b}, t, 
                  Method -> "NMinimize"]["BestFitParameters"]

{a -> 0.000783053, b -> 0.0147985}
```

The fit looks good:

```
Show[ListPlot@data, Plot[a Exp[b t] /. fit, {t, 248, 360}]]
```

[image]

See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2309/problem-with-nonlinearmodelfit) for more details on how the NMinimize method works.

Comment: Ahh, it seems my problem is having Mathematica 7! Thanks for the tip.